# How do I add the -shell-escape option in TexShop

Tags: macos, latex

I am using the `minted.sty` package and it is requiring that I use the `-shell-escape` option during latex/xelatex compile. I can do that over the console/terminal. However, I wish to add this option into TexShop. I am prior user of WinEdit on Windows but have recently switched to Mac and TexShop, so don't know how to do it?

Here is the console output:

```
Package ifplatform Warning: 
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
))
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape  flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.54 \makeatletter
```

Answer (score 26):

in case you are still looking for an answer:

- Go to the Preferences
- Go to Tab "Engine"
- Go to Field "pdfTeX"
- In the LaTeX Input Field add --shell-escape at the end.

**before:** `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1`

**after:** `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape`